# TF900560: Cannot set unknown member 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfsBuild.TargetsNotLogged.'

Tags: msbuild

I have a TFS build server that was on 2008, just upgraded it to 2010 for TFS 2013. Using the Upgrade template and pointing at the correct build server, I got `TF900560: Could not start build: Cannot set unknown member 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfsBuild.TargetsNotLogged.'` What does this mean? And what troubleshooting steps can I make?

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me like one of the configurations in your build script is no longer supported in 2010?  Is it possible to start stripping tasks out of your current build process and make it very simple, and get that building.  Then add back in one item at a time until it fails?